# How to swap classes with hover effect in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a 'div' container 'obj_image' having another 'div' 'like_icon' which if the user clicks in it, sends an ajax request and if it is success, change the class of the 'like_icon' for other. My problem is if I click once, it great, but the next time the element don't do anything, and I have to mouse leave of the 'obj_image' element to click another time.

HTML

```
<div class="obj_image">
    <div class="like_icon"></div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.obj_image').hover( function() {

     $('.obj_image:hover').find('.like_icon').bind('click', function() {            
        $.ajax({
            async: false,
            url:'url', 
            type: "POST",
            success: function(){
                $('.obj_image:hover').find('.like_icon').addClass('no_like_icon').removeClass('like_icon');
            },                
        });
     });

     $('.obj_image:hover').find('.no_like_icon').bind('click', function() {
        $.ajax({
            async: false,
            url:'', 
            type: "POST",
            success: function(){
                $('.obj_image:hover').find('.no_like_icon').addClass('like_icon').removeClass('no_like_icon');
            },                
        });
     });
});
});
```

Comment: why are you binding a click handler after a hover handler?  Shouldn't click work well enough without it?

Comment: I have several 'obj_image' elements and only give functionality when the pointer is over the element.

Comment: But if you click something, you are hovering over it as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.obj_image').hover( function() {

     $(this).find('.like_icon').bind('click', function() {            
        $.ajax({
            async: false,
            url:'url', 
            type: "POST",
            success: function(){
$(this).find('.like_icon').addClass('no_like_icon').removeClass('like_icon');
            },                
        });
     });
}, // this is the important part
function(){ //call the mouseleave function
     $(this).find('.no_like_icon').bind('click', function() {
        $.ajax({
            async: false,
            url:'', 
            type: "POST",
            success: function(){
$(this).find('.no_like_icon').addClass('like_icon').removeClass('no_like_icon');
            },                
        });
     });
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`.toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) function which would swap the classes for which is found, e.g.

```
$('.obj_image').hover(function()
{
    $(this).children('.no_like_icon').toggleClass('like_icon no_like_icon');
});
```

If `like_icon` is found, it will replace it with `no_like_icon`, otherwise the opposite.